# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el boton siguiente de datatables jquery avance 5 paginas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Quiero que al momento de dar click en el boton siguiente(next) de la tabla, avance por ejemplo 5 paginas y no solo 1 que es por default.

¿Cómo podría lograr eso?

Lo que he intentado hasta ahora es mostrar mas numeros de pagina en la tabla con:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.pager.numbers_length = 10;
```

Si bien muestra 3 paginas adicionales a la actual que esta seleccionada, no es lo que busco ya que ocupa mas espacio la paginacion.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
  $("tbody").append("<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + Math.random() + "</td></tr>");
}

$.fn.dataTableExt.pager.numbers_length = 10;

$("table").dataTable({
  ordering: false,
  info: false,
  bFilter: false,
  extPagination: {
    numbers_length: 600
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Random numbers</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te sugiero revisar la [documentación](https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthMenu) y podrías intentar usar la propiedad `lengthMenu`.

Comment: Tu pregunta ya había sido formulada hace rato, checate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383805/datatables-change-number-of-pagination-buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si nada mas funciona, hazlo manualmente, como este ejemplo.

Fíjate en la función que puse, cada vez que tocas next, se remplaza el elemento del botón y se pierde el handler así que hay que volver a configuración.

Saludos.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
  $("tbody").append("<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + Math.random() + "</td></tr>");
}

$.fn.dataTableExt.pager.numbers_length = 5;

var dt = $("table").dataTable({
  ordering: false,
  info: false,
  bFilter: false,
  extPagination: {
    numbers_length: 600
  }
});

// esto es lo que agregue <<<<<------
var page = 4;
(function modificaBoton() {
  $(".paginate_button.next").on('click', function() {
    dt.fnPageChange(page);
    page+=5;
    modificaBoton();
  })
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Random numbers</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias @rnd, me sirvio tu respuesta.